# Pushing a repository to my git remote repository failing with broken pipe

Tags: git, git-push

I am using eclipse Egit plugin. we have a repository to maintain all the libraries we use. So today i got to commit and push some 50 libraries files along with their sources into our remote repository (we have a server hosting our code base)

when i tried pushing i get following error. we use ssh for pushing and fetching contents from remote repository (not http).

```
error: file write error (Disk quota exceeded)9 MiB/s   
fatal: unable to write sha1 file
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
```

can some some explain why this was happening. did we miss setting some paramaters on server regarding some size limits for file content.

Comment: What OS/VM/filesystem are you using? This blog post is an example of *one* potential cause: http://samixblog.blogspot.com/2012/01/openvz-vzctl-disk-quota-exceeded-error.html

Comment: Server: Ubuntu 10.10
Client: Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: I just now did "git gc" on the remote repository. and then push from local passed. but i could not understand why this worked.

Comment: `git fc` must have diminish the size of the repo, allowing the git user to get more free space, under the quota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be a limitation on the Server OS (your Ubuntu 11.10), and you need to check if quotas have been activated (they aren't on by default).

This [article](http://www.idimmu.net/2010/08/26/Disk-Quotas-On-Ubuntu) explains how quotas are managed.
And check if the quota is coherent with what your git user n the server is actually using, as mentioned in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46059/disk-quota-exceeded-error).

```
 quota -su git
 # versus
 du -sh ~git
```

If not, a `quotacheck` is in order.